# how to hide a Button inside a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to hide a button (Button1) which is inside a DataGrid.

Follow my code and guide me...

```
<StackPanel>
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="grdTitle">

        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>

        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="expLocalVersions">
                <WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="grdVersion">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
                                <WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <Button x:Name="Button1"></Button>
                                </WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                             </WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                         </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </StackPanel>
                </WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: hide how? base on what conditions? or could you simple put `Visibility='Collapsed'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest Binding the Visible property of the button to a special Property of your Itemssource.
Like:

```
public Visibility ShowButton
{
    get { return (OtherProperty ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible); }
}
```

and

```
<Button Visible="{Binding Path=ShowButton}" />
```

Comment: That's really how you need to approach WPF in general. Change your object and the UI should automagically change.

Answer (score 0):

There goes I spent some time doing it and here is an example how it should be done

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                          Width="479" Margin="12,12,0,0" CanUserAddRows="False"  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" HeadersVisibility="All">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sr No" Binding="{Binding srNo}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some Title" Binding="{Binding ArticleTitle}" IsReadOnly="True" MaxWidth="290" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn  MinWidth="100" Header="View">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button  Visibility="{Binding Display}" Content="This Is the Button" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

**Code**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<ButtonDataGrid> data = new List<ButtonDataGrid>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                ButtonDataGrid dataToAdd = new ButtonDataGrid();

                dataToAdd.srNo = (x + 1).ToString();
                dataToAdd.ArticleTitle = "This is Article No " + dataToAdd.srNo;
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    dataToAdd.Display = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    dataToAdd.Display = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                data.Add(dataToAdd);
            }
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;
        }
    }
    public class ButtonDataGrid
    {
        public string srNo { get; set; }
        public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
        public Visibility Display { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Bravo! but i need to hide it on run time.... i cant call the button at any where in the code behind